# How to send a folder of files through Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, put

We currently have a cURL request like below and we'd like to convert it into Python. How do I do this? From my googling, all I am seeing is how to send files but not a folder files. Thank you!

```
curl 
--location 
--request PUT 'https://some-url.com/files' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--data-binary '@/path/to/files'
```

Comment: `--data-binary @filename` sends the contents of the file named `filename`; as far as the manual tells me, it doesn't send folders. And it can't, because the HTTP standard doesn't support this out of the box either.

Comment: Right.. so if this is the case, we loop through the directory and call `requests.put()` for every file? Is this the way to do it?

Comment: it should be the right way.

Comment: It is not possible to send a folder but you can zip the folder and send it.